# What is the song used when naruto asks iruka to be his dad for the marriage

Tags: naruto, music

At a point in episode 500 of the naruto series when naruto was getting married iruka got mad at him for not caring about how hard hinata was working for the wedding and in the whole fuss naruto asks him to be his  dad at the wedding and he almost cried. What song was used at that point?

Comment: Is the "Homecoming" or Kikyo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSsyvjfZsFo

Answer (score 1):

After a little of searching, I think it is called Man of The World

link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwZRUDbS25o

Answer (score 0):

its "kikyou" or "homecoming".

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Please add a link to the tracks so it easier for the OP to verify if they are correct